# Keep getting Trgval? no (false positive; hash > target),

Tags: bfgminer

Yes, I am a Noob. Getting acquainted with bitmining before I move up to big rigs investments. Learning rig is a RPI 3 B+ with Bitmain ASIC eruptors. Using BDGminer and get connection and hashes with it. Problem is, when computations done I recieve this:

trgval? no (false positive; hash > target)

Been researching and finding nothing to help. Changed pools changed scripts, but best is the Sha256 which the bitmain's are designed for. Kind of stuck right now and hope someone would have a clue to help.
Thanks

Comment: Did you find the answer to this?